# ref.once() not called on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am puzzeled with the following issue. While making a little web page to see some data I have on Firebase, there is some place where I cannot access what I want.
Of course I know there is something at this place on the server. Here is the code, it seems localRef.once() is never called.

```
var dbLocalURL = "https://atinytestapp.firebaseio.com/MyList/rc99/";
var localRef = new Firebase(dbLocalURL);
localRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    // WE NEVER COME HERE !!!!
    for (record in snapshot.val()) {
        document.write(record)
        var recordRef = new Firebase(dbLocalURL+record+"/");
        recordRef.once("value", function(rcdSnapshot) {
            var rcdData = rcdSnapshot.val();
            document.write(rcdData[“someKey”])
        })
    }
}, function (errorObject) {
    // WE NEVER COME HERE !!!!
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    document.write("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

My page accessing the data is working as it should about everywhere, except in one place with the above behaviour.
Beside I have also checked that the URL I use is correct, by pasting it into a browser and seeing the data I expect.
What can I be missing? I hope someone can give me a hint.

Comment: The code/flow works for me: http://jsbin.com/vujinaloci/edit?html,js,console. Can you set up a similar minimal jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 4):

(note: this is the new Firebase 3 way)
This wasn't included in the code in the question but here's the initialization on (here for completeness)

```
// Set the configuration for your app: Replace with your project's config object
  var config = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
```

and assuming you want to just read the data once:

```
firebase.database().ref('MyList/rc99').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    for (record in snapshot.val()) { //unordered records, see comment
       document.write(record)
       ...
```

Firebase 2

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://atinytestapp.firebaseio.com/MyList/rc99/");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(record) { //ordered records, see comment
    document.write(record)
    ...
});
```

Note: make sure the url is correct as if that's malformed it won't work at all. I tried your url and it doesn't seem to be responding.

Comment: Instead of `for (record in snapshot.val())`, use `snapshot.forEach()`. The latter will maintain the order of the children.

Comment: I finally solved the issue it was a synchro problem. I was not waiting for things to happen as I should. I had to fight with promises for a while and now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May be useful for someone: `once('value', function)` swallowed my error message. When I updated to `once('value').then(function)` I was able to see an error message in the console.